# Using regex to extract data from the following string

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like

```
st = " *  ** abc * def ghi **abc* mn*"
```

I would like to extract a list containing unique elements in between `*`s which in this case would be:

```
['abc', 'def ghi', 'mn']
```

My approach:

```
se = set([x.strip() for x in re.split('\*+', st)])
se.discard('')
l = list(se)
```

I am new to regular expressions. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you convert back to a list after?

Comment: better in what sense? better is a subjective term..

Comment: Do you want to preserve order?

Comment: @rock321987 I mean I had to use 'discard' function because split() could not remove empty string. But is there a way using only regular expression not to get empty string? and also not to have to use strip() function?

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi i have added pure regex solution..though its better to use `strip`

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for your answer, I think you're right that the pure RE solution is too complicated. So, I think it's better to accept holdenweb's answer especially with its comment.

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi its your will.though it turned to be much simpler than I expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a single statement:

```
se = list(set([x.strip() for x in re.split('\*+', st)]) - {''})
```

That isn't necessarily to be preferred over your solution for readability, however.

Comment: Here's an even shorter one `list(set(re.split('[ *]*\* *', st))-{''})`. But it's clearly not a very good solution, because it's so hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

No need to fire up the regex engine:

```
testcase = " *  ** abc * def ghi **abc* mn*"
list(set(s.strip() for s in testcase.split("*")) - {''})
```

Comment: Yeh, I formulated a strip-based solution before I came upon the `-{""}` trick to remove the empties.

Comment: You'd probably enjoy [Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> st = " *  ** abc * def ghi **abc* mn*"
>>>
>>> list(set(x.strip() for x in st.split('*') if x.strip()))
['mn', 'def ghi', 'abc']
```

Or if you prefer to using functions, then:

```
>>> st
' *  ** abc * def ghi **abc* mn*'
>>> l = []
>>> def f(x):
        x = x.strip()
        if x:
            return x


>>> for elem in st.split('*'):
        x = f(elem)
        if x and x not in l:
            l.append(x)


>>> l
['abc', 'def ghi', 'mn']
```

Answer (score -3):

Took data provided by you and tried the below code.
Since you mentioned of using regex, which sounds reasonable, I have this suggestion. You can improve upon this code and post your final version.

```
import re

st = " *  ** abc * def ghi **abc* mn*"

mystrs = re.compile('\w+')
allstrs = re.findall(mystrs, st)
print allstrs
```

Output:

['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc', 'mn']

Comment: This separates 'def' and 'ghi'!

Comment: My response crossed with the one from @holdenweb, his solution seems to be more appropriate to suit your needs.

Comment: That doesn't give the correct output. `['abc', 'def ghi', 'mn']`

Comment: And unless you know exactly Python's definition of an `re` word and you know it exactly matches the questioner's requirements (hint: it doesn't) it's a little lazy to rely on Python to inutit your meaning.